# How to check whether compute engine vm is operating at max core / sustained turbo frequency?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to evaluate GCP compute engine VM for my application workload. And today I've hit 100% cpu usage on n2 4 vCPUS and 8 GB RAM.

When i run the following command to see the frequency (in the snap below ) only 2.8 Ghz is shown.

`watch -n.1 "grep \"^[c]pu MHz\" /proc/cpuinfo"`

**Question**:

- Is it possible to get the max core turbo frequency utilized on n2 machine as mentioned in the doc below of 3.9 / 3.4 GHZ ?

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms#intel_cpu_processors

[image: cpu info]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turbo frequency or Single-core max turbo frequency is not a VM setting to change. According with the [Official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms#frequency_behavior) Most VMs get the all-core turbo frequency, even if only the base frequency is advertised to the guest environment.

In theory it *should* be turbo-on-demand, the default machine behavior is to let the CPU boost to whatever frequency it wants.

On the other hand,  /proc/cpuinfo will always report the base frequency, and not the actual operating frequency.

In other cases, I would said that you could run [turbostat](https://www.linux.org/docs/man8/turbostat.html) to measure the actual operating frequency, but unfortunately [turbostat is not supported to running on virtual machines.](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-pm/patch/1501243581-31491-2-git-send-email-prarit@redhat.com/), you could check [this other post](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196371) to further information.

It is worth noting that turbo frequency is based on the [turbo boost technology of Intel CPUs](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/gaming/resources/turbo-boost.html). The core frequency is set according to the type of computation performed.

All-core turbo frequency: The frequency at which each CPU typically runs when all cores in the socket are not idle at the same time.